# stripe add bank transfer while user checkout

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, strip

In stripe checkout page, I'm trying to add bank_transfer, so I have updated my code like below.

```
$customer = $this->StripeClient->customers->create([
            'email' => $entUser->email,
]);

[
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'line_items' => [
            [
                'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'jpy',
                'product_data' => [
                    -----
                ],
                'mode' => 'payment',
                'success_url' => url("/payment-success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"),
                'cancel_url' => url('/payment-fail?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'),
                'payment_method_types' => [
                    'card',
                    'customer_balance',
                ],
                'payment_method_options' => [
                    'customer_balance' => [
                        'funding_type' => 'bank_transfer',
                        'bank_transfer' => ['type' => 'jp_bank_transfer'],
                    ],
                ],
                'payment_intent_data' => [
                    'application_fee_amount' => ceil( ($bookEnt->price * env('PRODUCT_FEE'))/100 ),
                ],
            ],['stripe_account' => $authorEnt->stripe_id]
]
```

Problem is I'm getting error

**The payment method `customer_balance` requires `customer` to be set.**

Do I require any setting in dashboard ? How can I solve this problem ?

After Jonathan Steele ans , I have added require changes. Now getting error

```
**No such customer: 'cus_NOmPYSaG7idd'**
```

I have debug the customer and also check dashboard, customer object has created.

Then why this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/bank-transfers/accept-a-payment?platform=checkout#create-or-retrieve-a-customer) bank transfer payments must be associated with a Customer object. You need to create (or retrieve) a `cus_xxx` object and pass it during Checkout Session creation via the `customer` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer).

Comment: Okay , I solved the issue after add ['stripe_account' => $authorEnt->stripe_id] when creating client !